# failed to connect with winsock - error 10049 on c

Tags: c, eclipse, windows, client-server, winsock

Iv'e tried to run server client between 2 computers in my local network in my house.

I failed with error 10049 in the client side. I thought it was something with firewall so I've tried to run it my computer(with threads), but still the same issue.
I'm failing at function "connect" with my output:

"error - connect failed. sockfd is 188, errno is 34, WSA is 10049"

here's my code.

app.c:

```
#include "client.h"
#include "server.h"


int main()
{
    DWORD dwThreadID1, dwThreadID2;

    CreateThread(
                     NULL,         // default security attributes
                     0,            // default stack size
                     (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE) apserver,
                     NULL,         // no thread function arguments
                     0,            // default creation flags
                     &dwThreadID1); // receive thread identifier
    CreateThread(
                         NULL,         // default security attributes
                         0,            // default stack size
                         (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE) apClient,
                         NULL,         // no thread function arguments
                         0,            // default creation flags
                         &dwThreadID2); // receive thread identifier
    while(1)
    {}

    return 0;
}
```

server.c:

```
#include "server.h"


int socketBind(int sockfd, int port){
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    ZeroMemory((char*) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(port);
    if ( bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0 ){
        // we can check errno for exact ERROR
        printf("bind failed with errno %d\n",errno);fflush(NULL);
        return ERROR;
    }
    if ( listen(sockfd, 100) == -1 ){
        return ERROR;
    }
    return 1;
}

DWORD WINAPI apserver(LPVOID lpParam)
{
    WSADATA wsaData;

        if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsaData) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
            printf ("Error initialising WSA.\n");
            return -1;
        }
    int sockfd; // server's listening socket's descriptor id
    int port = 4997;
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    while ( sockfd < 0 ){ // ERROR
        printf("Listener socket creation failed with:%d, errno is %d\n",sockfd,errno);fflush(NULL);
        sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    }
    if ( socketBind(sockfd, port) == ERROR ){
        printf("Socket bind failed with errno=%d\n",errno);fflush(NULL);
        close(sockfd);
        return ERROR;
    }
    printf("Starting to listen to other USERS!\n");fflush(NULL);
    struct sockaddr_in cli_addr;
    int clilen = sizeof(cli_addr); // length of address
    // accept() returns the socket that will be used for Control Connection with the accepted client
    printf("*************Waiting for other USERS************\n");fflush(NULL);
    int newsockfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&cli_addr, &clilen);
    int readLength;
    char command[(128+1)];
    while(1)
    {
        ZeroMemory(command, sizeof(command));
        readLength = read(newsockfd, command, 128+1);
        if(readLength == 0)
        {
            continue;
        }
        if(readLength > 0)
        {
            printf(" here should be API's func to command %s", command);fflush(NULL);
        }
        else
        {
            close(sockfd);
            close(newsockfd);
            WSACleanup();
            printf("Read failed with errno:%d\n",errno);fflush(NULL);
            return ERROR;
        }
    }
    close(sockfd);
    close(newsockfd);
    WSACleanup();
    return 1;
}
```

client.c:

```
#include "client.h"

int verifyWrite(int sockfd, char* command){
    int size = strlen(command);
    int i=0, x=0;
    for(i=0;i<size;){
        x = write(sockfd, command, size);
        if(x < 0){
            return ERROR;
        }
        if(x >= 0) {
            i += x;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int sendToAll(char* message, int sockfd)
{
    if ( verifyWrite(sockfd, message) < 0 )
    {
        printf("error while sending message\n");fflush(NULL);
    }
    return 0;
}

DWORD WINAPI apClient(LPVOID lpParam)
{
    WSADATA wsaData;

    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsaData) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf ("Error initialising WSA.\n");
        return -1;
    }
    int port,sockfd;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);       //creating control connection
    while(sockfd < 0){
        printf("error - sockfd = %d\n",sockfd);fflush(NULL);
        sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    }
    port = 4997;
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.x.x");
    ZeroMemory((char*)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(port);
    while(connect(sockfd,(struct sockaddr*)&serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0){
        printf("error - connect failed. sockfd is %d, errno is %d, WSA is %d\n",sockfd,errno,WSAGetLastError());fflush(NULL);
    }
    printf("\n opened connection to %s\n", "192.168.x.x");fflush(NULL);

    int i = 0;
    while(i< 6)
    {
        sendToAll("just a message", sockfd);
        i++;
    }

    WSACleanup();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You know that addresses in the `192.168.x.x` range are private, so nobody else outside your network will be able to connect that that address, so no need to censor it. :)

Comment: yes I knew it, but I saw everyone here censor it so I thought maybe Im wrong :P

Answer (score 2):

Windows socket error `10049` is `WSAEADDRNOTAVAIL`, and if you [read about it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740668%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#WSAEADDRNOTAVAIL) you will see that

> `connect`, ... when the remote address or port is not valid for a remote computer (for example, address or port 0).

The reason is very simple:

```
serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.x.x");
ZeroMemory((char*)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
```

You clear the structure *after* you set the address you want to connect to.

Comment: thanks a lot.
I read it, I just didn't noticed to the zeroMemory.